# How can I optimize this 'lottery' function in PHP?

Tags: php, optimization, combinations

Earlier I wrote a code in Matlab for this sort of lottery function, just to test if it was possible. However, I actually needed it in PHP so I've just rewritten the code and it does seem to work, but as it involves a lot of looping I want to make sure I'm doing it as efficiently as possible.

What the code does:

You can call the function `$lotto -> type($users,$difficulty)` and it will return two numbers. Here's the explanation, `$users` is the number of users registered on the website, i.e the people who will potentially buy a ticket. `$difficulty` is a number between 1 and 10, where 5 is normal, 1 is easy and 10 is hard. Difficulty here means how hard it is to match all numbers on a lottery ticket.

So what are the numbers that the function returns? That would be `$n` and `$r`. `$n` is the amount of numbers there will be on the lottery ticket, and `$r` is the amount of numbers you can choose from the lottery ticket. For example, in the UK a national lottery ticket has 49 numbers if which you choose 6. I.e `$n = 49` and `$r = 6`.

How does the function calculate these two numbers? In the UK national lottery there are 13,983,816 different possible ticket combinations. If I were to run `$lotto -> type(13983816,1)` it would return `array(49,6)`. Basically it tried to make it so there are as many combinations of tickets as there are registered users.

tl;dr, here's the code:

```
<?php
class lotto {
    public function type($users,$difficulty){
        $current_r = $r = 2;
        $current_n = 0;
        $difficulty = ($difficulty + 5) / 10; // sliding scale from 1 - 10
        $last_tickets_sold = 200; // tickets sold in last lotto
        $last_users = 100; // how many users there were in the last lotto
        $last_factor = $last_tickets_sold / $last_users; // tickets per user
        $factor = $last_factor * $difficulty;
        $users *= $factor;
        while($r <= 10){
            $u = 0;
            $n = $r;
            while($u < $users && $n < 50){
                $u = $this -> nCr(++$n,$r);
            }
            if($r == 2){
                $current_n = $n;
            } elseif(abs($this -> nCr($n,$r) - $users) < abs($this -> nCr($current_n,$current_r) - $users)){
                // this is a better match so update current n and r
                $current_r = $r;
                $current_n = $n;
            }
            $r++;
        }
        return array($current_n,$current_r);
    }
    private function nCr($n,$r){
        return $this -> factorial($n) / (
            $this -> factorial($r) * $this -> factorial($n - $r)
        );
    }
    private function factorial($x){
        $f = $x;
        while(--$x){
            $f *= $x;
        }
        return $f;
    }
}
$lotto = new lotto;
print_r($lotto -> type(1000,5));
?>
```

Comment: One small optimization is to store previous results of the factorial in an array so you do not have to do a long calculation each time. Which would map a map of input => output. This should cut down on the processing time of the factorials greatly. You can also store the last known value as you have two always increasing numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick scan and spotted a few places that can be further optimized.

**Combination**
Your algorithm is a brute force one and can be further optimized

```
private function nCr($n,$r){
    return $this -> factorial($n) / (
        $this->factorial($r) * $this->factorial($n - $r)
    );
}
```

to

```
function nCr($n,$r) {
    $top = 1;
    $sub = 1;

    for($i = $r+1; $i <= $n; $i++)
        $top *= $i;

    $n -= $r;
    for($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++)
        $sub *= $i;

    return $top / $sub;
}
```

**Too Much Combination Calculation**
Calculate combination is expensive.

```
$u = 0;
$n = $r;
while($u < $users && $n < 50){
    $u = $this -> nCr(++$n,$r);
}
```

to

```
$n = $r + 1;
$u = nCr($n, $r);

while ($u < $users && $n < 50) {
    $n++;
    $u *= $n;
    $u /= ($n - $r);
}
```

Comment: Didn't get a chance to check the output of these to work with the OP's code, but this is the only answer to the question.

Comment: Lovely, just benchmarked the before and after:

100x original ~= .159 seconds
100x new code ~= .0174 seconds

Remarkable improvement, thanks a lot :), I've upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

An immediate observation is that you have the possibility of a divide by 0 error

```
$last_factor = $last_tickets_sold / $last_users;
```

Could be solved by putting a simple if statement around it

```
$last_factor = ($last_users == 0) ? 0 : $last_tickets_sold / $last_users;
```

Comment: But `$last_users = 100;`, a statically defined value. If this generated a divide by 0 error, it'd be an epic PHP bug.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm assuming (yes I know, assumption is wrong), that these values are going to be changed for dynamic values pulled from a db. But yes, given the current code that's not possible. Just an observation

Comment: Your assumption is correct, it will be pulled from a database, however there is the possibility that 0 users used the lottery last time so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless detailed examination of your code, are you sure that your loops does not need continue or break?

Comment: Definitely not, they only go as high as n = 50 and r = 10, and I need to try each possibility for a better match.

Answer (score 0):

The range of **factorial()** in your algo is [0,50], so why not just precompute this statically?

```
private static $factorial=array(1);

private static genFactorial($max) {
    if( count( self::$factorial ) > $max ) return;
    foreach ( range(count(self::$factorial), $max) as $n ) {
        self::$factorial[$n] = $i*self::$factorial[$n-1];
    }
}
```

Now add a `self::genFactorial(50);` to `__construct()` or to `type()` and replace references to `$this -> factorial($n)` by `self::$factorial[$n]`.

This is just a quick code dump; not even compile checked so forgive any typos, etc.  but what this does is to replace a function call (which includes a while loop) by an array element fetch.